# How to use Eval statement to check a column value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<asp:GridView ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="false" AlternatingRowStyle-BackColor="#EBE9E9" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnSorting="yourTasksGV_Sorting" AllowSorting="true" ID="yourTasksGV" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" EmptyDataText="You currently have no tasks assigned to you" OnRowDataBound="yourTasksGV_RowDataBound" OnRowCreated="yourTasksGV_RowCreated">
    <Columns>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderStyle-Width="2%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/theImages/Dependencies.png" CssClass="gvTaskDep btnShowDepend" runat="server" ID="btnShowDepend" OnCommand="btnShowDepend_Command" CommandName="TaskDepend" AlternateText='<%#Eval("Object") + "," + Eval("FK") %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("Object") + "," + Eval("FK") %>' ToolTip="Click to view Dependencies" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:HyperLinkField HeaderStyle-Width="16%" Target="_self" DataNavigateUrlFields="Task Detail" DataTextField="Task Name" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="" HeaderText="Task Detail" SortExpression="Task Name" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <!-- ADD ANOTHER COLUMN HERE -->
        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="10%" DataField="Workgroup" HeaderText="Workgroup" SortExpression="Workgroup" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="7%" DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="Status" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
        <asp:BoundField HeaderStyle-Width="7%" DataField="Due Date" HeaderText="Due" SortExpression="Due Date" ItemStyle-CssClass="taskTableColumn" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I am populating my GridView like this:

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(gs))
{
    try
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(query, conn);

        myDataSet = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(myDataSet);

        myDataView = new DataView();
        myDataView = myDataSet.Tables[0].DefaultView;

        yourTasksGV.DataSource = myDataView;
        yourTasksGV.DataBind();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        string error = ex.Message;
    }
}
```

How can I modify my ASP.net GridView on this line: `<!-- ADD ANOTHER COLUMN HERE -->`, where the column will check the value in column `Due Date` in each row and make the background color red, if the `Due Date` column value is before today's date.

I would like to use an `Eval` statement.

This is what I have:

```
public string GetTodayDate()
{
    return DateTime.Now.ToString("mm-dd-yyyy");
}

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="V%">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <!-- FILL ENTIRE CELL? -->
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlTaskStats" Width="100%" Height="100%" runat="server" BackColor="<%# (Eval("Due Date").ToString() < GetTodayDate()) ? "#C00000" : "" %>"></asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>                   
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I get the following error:

```
`Operator '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'`
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78549/discussion-on-question-by-searchforknowledge-how-to-use-eval-statement-to-check).

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

C# code:

```
public Color DueDateBG (DateTime DueDate)
{
    Color clr = //whatever default colour

    if(DueDate < DateTime.Today) 
    {
        //Any further logic for deciding on colour
    }

    return clr;
}
```

ASP.NET code:

```
BackColor="<%# DueDateBG(Eval("Due Date").ToString()) %>"
```

Note that this would only change the background of your label, and not the entire cell as your further comments suggest you're aiming for.

Using RowDataBound you can access the entire row and alter it like this:

```
protected void yourTasksGV_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        DateTime dt = (DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DueDate");
        if(dt < DateTime.Today) 
        {
             e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
             //or do it for a specific cell
             e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

ASP.NET Code add the event to the GridView:

```
OnRowDataBound="yourTasksGV_RowDataBound"
```

On a side note, if you want to make sure that the value in DueDate is indeed a DateTime then you can use TryParse as done above by Naveen. So replace:

```
DateTime dt = (DateTime)DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DueDate");
```

with:

```
DateTime dt;
DateTime.TryParse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "DueDate").ToString(), out dt)
```

Comment: `BackColor` is a property of what here? Eval does not work for attributes of `TemplateField`, only for attributes of its content controls

Comment: @Andrei - no, but it is of Label. However, having read the additional comments it looks like he's not trying to alter just the label background.

Comment: Yeah. I want to color the entire cell as red. But it is almost here :)

Comment: I get this error: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.DateTime'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?) `

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge - updated. Forgot to cast to DateTime when getting the value from the dataitem from the DataBinder.

Comment: What is being pulled here: `DateTime.TryParse(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Due Date").ToString(), out dt);`

Comment: `var k = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, "Due Date");` This is null

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge -  the TryParse is ensuring that the value you have in DueDate is able to be converted into a dateTime. If it can then it will parse it into 'dt'. As for your next comment, are you sure DueDate has a correct date value? If so can you give an example of the date being parsed? You may need to use TryParseExact to be able to specify the exact format the date is currently in.

Answer (score 1):

Write a small helper function.

Markup

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="lblPD" runat="server" Text="blah" BackColor='<%# SetBackGroundColor(Eval("[Due Date]")) %>'>
            blah blah
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Code-behind

```
protected System.Drawing.Color SetBackGroundColor(object item)
{
    DateTime dueDate;
    var bg = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    if (item != null && DateTime.TryParse(item.ToString(), out dueDate))
    {
        if (dueDate < DateTime.Today)
        {
            bg = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
    return bg;
}
```

Another hack ( ugly cos it has no null checking ) will be

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="lblPD1" runat="server" Text="blah1" 
            BackColor='<%# DateTime.Parse(Eval("[Due Date]").ToString()) < DateTime.Today ? System.Drawing.Color.Red : System.Drawing.Color.Black %>'>
            blah
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I need a Panel rather than a label because I would want to entire cell to be red.

Comment: `The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0.` error.

Comment: Does it check for column for each row?

Comment: use `TryParseExact` with your dateformat. something like. `DateTime.TryParseExact(newItem, "MM-d-yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.None, out dueDate)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Edit">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <a href='Registration.aspx?key=<%#Eval("yourTasksGV_Sorting") %>'>Edit</a>
                                </ItemTemplate>
```

Comment: I know how to use it. Just would like to figure out the conditional statement inside the `Eval`. Thanks.